# two frame titles in beamer

Tags: beamer, frame-title

In a beamer presentation I would like to put both the conclusions and acknowledgements on a single slide. Visually, I would like to first have the "Conclusions" caption, then some bullets, then the "Acknowledgements" caption and finally some acknowledgement bullets. "Conclusions" and "Acknowledgements" should have the same formatting. I will generate "Conclusions" using `\frametitle`. Beamer does not accept two `\frametitle`s in a single slide, so is there some other way to put text with the same formatting as the frame title?

Comment: Well probably not as you do not have two headers on one frame (top of the frame has usually special formatting). But to help you we need to see a MWE.

Comment: @TeXnician As indicated below I did not include an MWE because I was hoping for a general solution. samcarter has understood the question properly, so I think his example can be used to show the result I am after.

Comment: @Octaviour Even if you are looking for a general solution, you could have written a general MWE. If it does nothing else, it would save people willing to help you from writing `\documentclass{beamer} ... \begin{document}... \end{document}` for the 1000th time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you gave no MWE nor any indication which theme you are using, I'm going to answer for the default theme.

```
\documentclass{beamer}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}

text

\vfill
{\hskip-1.8em\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle} blub}
\vfill
text

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not specify the theme as I was hoping there was a generic way of doing this. `\usebeamerfont` and `\usebeamercolor` seem to go a long way. Is the vertical spacing standard among themes or did you customize that to match the default theme?

Comment: @Octaviour Did you have a change to look at your old questions? I did not specify any vertical spacing, just used fill to spread out the text over the page.

Comment: @samcater Does beamer always put a `\vfill` before and after the main content of the slide, or is that specific to the theme?

Comment: @Octaviour There is no general answer for the alignment, as there are different possible alignments. I simply used the `\vfill` to distribute the content on the slide.